# Why is the ROWID column that comes with every fusion table hidden?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have been adding an ID column to my Fusion Tables, but it appears this is not needed because every Fusion Table automatically comes with a ROWID column that auto populates.  Why is this column hidden and how do I change this so that it is displayed?

It makes no sense to me that it is hidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with the Fusion Tables UI, but there's a feature request for it that you can add your star to: https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=859